# Swift: array check for object at index

Tags: arrays, swift, swift2, datamodel, optional-values

I have an data model object with several properties. I have a dynamic array that will sometimes have some but not all of the object properties inside of it.

How do I safely check if the array as anything at it's index

DataModel

```
class Order{
     var item0:String?
     var item1:String?
     var item2:String?
}
```

Array:

```
var myArray = [String]()
```

The guard statements are where I'm having issues checking to see if there are elements inside the array at different indexes.

Btw the array will never have more then 3 elements inside of it.

```
let order = Order()
order.item0 = "hat"
order.item1 = "sneakers"

myArray.append(order.item0)
myArray.append(order.item1)
//sometimes there may or may not be item2

let placedOrder = Order

//These guard statements aren't working
guard case let placedOrder.item0 = myArray[0] else {return}

guard case let placedOrder.item1 = myArray[1] else {return}

//There isn't anything at myArray[2] but I need to safely check anyway
guard case let placedOrder.item2 = myArray[2] else {return}
```

Comment: just use an `if myArray.count < 3` or whatever

Comment: I wouldn't use an array for storing properties. I would create a **struct** with different properties.

Comment: @Paulw11 I think that won't be a good mechanism. Because you may want to know which parameter is nil...

Comment: I also thought of a dictionary, but it isn't really clear what the OP is trying to achieve; it seems that they just want to know how many items are in the array, but the use of 3 separate strings is a bad design anyway.

Comment: @Paulw11 why is it bad design? I can explain what I'm doing in more detail but I was trying to keep things simple

Comment: The reason I say it is bad design is because using 3 separate variables is more complicated than using an array; you need to write repeated lines of code to access them rather than using a loop and if you needed to expand from 3 items then it just gets worse.  Since your properties are optional, you can just check for `nil` anyway rather than having an associated array.

Comment: @honey your exactly right, I also need to test for nil

Comment: Still seems to be more complicated than it needs to be, but anyway, can't you just check `myArray.count`?

Comment: I can check and loop through the array but where I'm lost at is attaching whatever elements are inside the array to the datamodel property that would correspond ti that element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st The array should hold the data model type and not it's properties:

```
var orders = [Order]() 
//changed the array's name from myArray to orders instead
```

2nd Add the data model object to the array:

```
let orderOne = Order()

orders.append(orderOne)
```

3rd loop through the array, check that the element's properties aren't nil:

```
for order in orders{

    if order.item0 != nil{
       //do something with order.item0
    }

    if order.item1 != nil{
       //do something with order.item1
    }

    if order.item2 != nil{
       //do something with order.item2
    }
}
```